# external links not working in phonegap

Tags: cordova, android-studio

I'm working on a phonegap project but i got problems with external links,
here is the code:

`<a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://cafebazaar.ir/app/com.zamangar.alarm.saharkhiz/', '_system');">Click Me</a>`

cafebazaar is an app store, I expect this link to be opened in the cafebazaar application or at least in a web browser, but the link doesn't work! it actually reacts like a normal text with link style :|

I used a normal html anchor too, like this:

`<a href="https://cafebazaar.ir/app/com.zamangar.alarm.saharkhiz/">Click Me</a>`

but it doesn't work too :(

PhoneGap version: 0.4.3

And I compile android application using android studio